# Seed в EntityFramework CodeFirst вставляет записи в неверной кодировке

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, кодировка, entity-framework

Пытаюсь через Migrations в MSSQLLocalDB вставить первоначальные данные на русском с помощью Seed.

```
protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
{
     //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version       
     context.WatchedApps.AddOrUpdate(
            new WatchedApp {AppId = 11, AppName = "Русская строка"});
}
```

В базу вставляются кракозябры - где-то ошибка в кодировке.

Charset в ConnectionString не поддерживается (ошибка при Update-Database)

Создание базы с Collation Cyrillic_General_CI_AS не помогло.

Через тест вставка проходит нормально, русские символы сохраняются правильно.

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Убедитесь что соответствующее поле в БД - юникодово.
2. Проверьте кодировку самого .cs файла

Comment: Это: Убедитесь что соответствующее поле в БД - юникодово. Очевидно Enable-Migrations создает файл Configuration.cs не в Unicode. Спасибо

Comment: Можно поподробнее о том как создать его в unicode?